# How to restict zipcode on checkout form in magento

Tags: onepage-checkout, zipcode

I want to restrict all zipcodes except the two zipcodes on checkout form at frontend. So as the user will input any zipcode different above two the order should not be placed.

I found this extension https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-restriction.html  It deos not allow specific zipcode that they want to restrict. but I want to restict all zipcodes besides two above.

I am using persistent checkout form. Below is the image of my check out form-

[image]

Till now what I was doing that I have applied a **jquery blur** function on zipcode text input it check zipcode on blur. In this case it works fine but when user use autofills property of browser, it bypass my function and it allow user to checkout with any zipcode so now I want to check zipcode on click event of button **Continue**.

Can anyone advise me what Can I do ? Is there any observer that is called on click on continue button(above image) in billing information.
Please feel free to ask any question?

Comment: Please Check This link may be it's use full for you.<br>
[Restrict COD](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439761/how-to-restrict-default-cod-in-magento-to-certain-zip-codes-only) [Restrict COD 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299718/cash-on-delivery-payment-method-should-visible-only-for-some-zip-codes-pin-codes)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this extension may be this extension fulfill your requirement 
[Ristrict Zip code on checkout](https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/shipping-filter-by-zip-code.html)

I believe some more extension available on magento connect as per your needed please find on magento connect

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Prateek. But above extension is paid and there are only 2 free extensions on magento connect and they give that I don't need.

Comment: Pls check this link 1) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16439761/how-to-restrict-default-cod-in-magento-to-certain-zip-codes-only  2) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29299718/cash-on-delivery-payment-method-should-visible-only-for-some-zip-codes-pin-codes

Comment: thanks prateek for deeg my question more. But I dont want to override any core function even in my local directory. Is there not any observer that  is called on click on continue button(above image) in billing information.?

Comment: @Pratik, The extension which you described in your answer is not exist now. please check once